# How to keep the formatting of the source in a dropdown menu?

Tags: colors, dropdown

Good morning,
New here so, please in advance excuse me if not very clear.
Here is my problem:
I have created large dependent drop-down lists through both the INDIRECT function and the VLOOKUP function (interesting but painful exercise).
The results are drawn from lists. Those list are formatted with color codes.
For instance my list SEC_PRIV is made of 5 lines:
- Creation (in blue)
- Renforcement des capacites (in green)
- etc...
When I select one of those, the subsequent activities are also color coded in the same colors in the source lists.

I would like, when I select those, that the results appearing in my selection cell, keep the color of the source lines.

Here are the tables to clarify maybe:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuhc1.png)
- on the table "source list", you can see that "CREATION" is in blue. However you can also see that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BMEp.png)
- on the dropdown result table "CREATION" appears in black.

How to I get the "CREATION" in the dropdown result table to keep the color of the source (blue) CREATION, even if I was to change the color of the source later?

Thank you in advance for your help before I have no hair left at all!

Flox

Comment: Can you please specify what Spreadsheet app you are using + version (e.g. MS Excel 2013, Google Sheet, LibreOffice XYZ....)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am on Excel 365.